# no error after forgetting Schema() in voluptuous

Tags: python, voluptuous

According to examples, this is the correct way to create a validation Schema:

```
import voluptuous as vol
PORT1 = vol.Schema(vol.All(int, vol.Range(min=0, max=65535)))
```

However, I noticed, that the `Schema` call is missing in some of my validators, e.g.:

```
PORT2 = vol.All(int, vol.Range(min=0, max=65535))
```

I checked that `PORT1` and `PORT2` are not of the same type. The catch is that `PORT2` works fine for me and gives the same results as the correct `PORT1`.

I don't know if I made a mistake. Could somebode please clearly state if it is an error to omit the `Schema(...)`? Why it works so well without the `Schema(...)` that I did not notice any problems?

Answer (score 2):

Every validator has a `__call__` defined for in the `validators`. You can see the source code below

https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous/blob/master/voluptuous/validators.py#L279

So even if you have

```py
PORT3 = vol.Range(min=0, max=65535)
PORT3(100)
```

This will also work. As you said, `PORT1` and `PORT2` are different objects but the `__call__` method is defined on all `validators` as well ones derived from `_WithSubValidators`

https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous/blob/2e557f71db6260e3ab40a6848a6bf4705d434f2d/voluptuous/validators.py#L184

The `Schema` object is wrapper around these validators to check an object as such.

In your case since you are only validating individual fields or combining them together with other validators, they will work perfectly fine

[image: Working]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Could you also answer the first question? `Schema()` is obviously needed when building a validator based on basic data types (`dict`, `list` etc.).  But why the examples from voluptuous README.md file show e.g. `s=Schema(All(..))` when `s=All(..)` does the job, because `All` is a validator?

Comment: Because you want to test a Schema and not just a particular value. It is the implementation which allows you to do it without the `Schema` also. Was it an intentional behavior by the author or it is just a side effect of how things have been implemented, I can't say. But one thing I would recommend is to use `Schema` always so that you are compatible with the future upgrades also

Comment: I wish voluptuous authors/maintainers were listening here and giving authoritative answers for this tag. I'm still confused. Using `Schema` is a safe bet of course, but my intution says a mandatory `Schema` would imply nonsense like this: `Schema(Any(Schema(All(Schema(a1), Schema(a2)), Schema(b))))`

Comment: Any and All doesn't necessary needs to have a Schema wrapper. Consider this like Lego blocks, you can join multiple ones and use the way you like